# How to install yate-qt4 on ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, sip

I would like to install the following package on an `ubuntu 18.04`:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yate/5.4.0-1-1ubuntu2
`yate-qt4`.

I have an existing ubuntu installation that I once upgraded from 16.x, and there the `yate` client was just kept.

Now I'm reinstalling 18.04 directly, and cannot find a way to force installation of the yate client again.

If I downloaded the *.tar.gz from the url, what would I have to do with it in order to install yate?

Comment: https://docs.yate.ro/wiki/Community lists support channels which may have an answer for you more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answer below, but ran into a collision. It looks like "yate-client" installs "yate" as a requisite:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libspandsp2 yate yate-client
```

but then gives this collision:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/yate-client_6.0.1-ubuntu1-sico1~bionic_amd64.deb (--unpack):
  trying to overwrite '/etc/yate/fileinfo.conf', which is also in package yate 6.0.1-ubuntu1-sico1~bionic
```

This command-sequence gets around it

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sico/yate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install yate-client
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try packages from [*“Silver Connection” team* PPA](https://launchpad.net/~sico/+archive/ubuntu/yate/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=bionic):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sico/yate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install yate-client
```